# Calculate the radius of convergence and the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose $u_0=1$ and $v_0=0$, then for all $n\geq 0$ 
$$ u_{n+1}=-u_n-2v_n,~~v_{n+1}=3u_n+4v_n$$
Calculate the radius of convergence and the sum of $\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{u_n}{n!}x^n$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{v_n}{n!}x^n$.

I thought about the matrix representation to solve the question so
$$ \left( {\begin{array}{c}
u_{n+1} \\
v_{n+1} \\ 
\end{array} } \right)
= 
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
-1 & -2 \\
3 &  4\\ 
\end{array} } \right] 
\left( {\begin{array}{c}
u_{n} \\
v_{n} \\ 
\end{array} } \right)$$
where
$$ \left( {\begin{array}{c}
u_{n} \\
v_{n} \\ 
\end{array} } \right) = 
A^n \left( {\begin{array}{c}
u_{0} \\
v_{0} \\ 
\end{array} } \right) ~\text{and}~
A = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
-1 & -2 \\
3 &   4 \\ 
\end{array} } \right]$$

I think I need now to work on the eigenvalues and eigen vectors but I don't have an idea how to do so!

Comment: Well, the "eigenvalue equation" for A is $\left|\begin{array}{cc}-1- \lambda & -2\\ 3 & 4-\lambda \end{array}\right|= (1- \lambda)(4- \lambda)+ 6= 4- 5\lambda+ \lambda^2+ 6= \lambda^2- 5\lambda+ 10= 0$.  Now do you see what the eigenvalues are?

Comment: Well, the "eigenvalue equation" for A is $\left|\begin{array}{cc}-1- \lambda & -2\\ 3 & 4-\lambda \end{array}\right|= (1- \lambda)(4- \lambda)+ 6= 4- 5\lambda+ \lambda^2+ 6= \lambda^2- 5\lambda+ 10= 0$.  You can use the quadratic formula to solve that equation.  It has two complex solutions.

Comment: @user247327 thanks a lot, my main problem is what to do after! i.e how to benefit from these values to find the answer

Comment: By the way it is $(-1-\lambda)(4- \lambda)+6$ which gives $\lambda=1, 2$

Answer (score 1):

If you write out a few terms of $u_n$ and $v_n$, you can see a pattern of $$u_n = -2 \cdot 2^n+3, v_n = 3 \cdot 2^n-3$$

This can be proven more explicitly through an inductive approach: If we assume that is the rule for $u_n$ and $v_n$, then $$u_{n+1} = -(-2 \cdot 2^n+3) - 2(3 \cdot 2^n-3) = - 4 \cdot 2^n + 3 = -2 \cdot 2^{n+1} + 3$$

$$v_{n+1} = 3(-2 \cdot 2^n+3) + 4(3 \cdot 2^n-3) = 6 \cdot 2^n - 3 = 3 \cdot 2^{n+1} - 3$$

Using that, we can see that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-2 \cdot 2^n+3}{n!}x^n$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{v_n}{n!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3 \cdot 2^n-3}{n!}x^n$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: sorry for late reply! I really like this solution and it is really very short and clever but don't you think it is very hard to get the formula for $u_n$ and $v_n$ from the pattern ? could you please what indications led you to the formulas?

Comment: Well after I wrote out some terms, I saw that they (about) doubled each time. This led me to a formula of the form $a \cdot 2^n + b$. From there, I plugged in two points and found the formula. It was partially luck that I noticed that the terms doubled each time.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- calculate eigenvalues, you'll get $1$ and $2$
- calculate associated eigenvectors, for instance $(1,-1)$ and $(-2,3)$
- what can be said about $a_n=u_n+v_n$ and $b_n=3u_n+2v_n$
- solve the equation for $a_n$ and $b_n$
- report in $u_n$ and $v_n$

Alternately for the third point, you can calculate the matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-1&3\end{bmatrix}$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$ so that $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$.

You'll notice by the form of $P^{-1}$ that it comes back to introducing $a_n$ and $b_n$ by setting $$\begin{pmatrix}a_n\\b_n\end{pmatrix}=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}u_n\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$$

---

Here is a variant to solve it.

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ is $\chi(x)=2-3x+x^2$, so by Cayley-Hamilton $\chi(A)=A^2-3A+2I=0$.

Applying to $\chi(A)\begin{pmatrix}u_n\\v_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u_{n+2}\\v_{n+2}\end{pmatrix}-3\begin{pmatrix}u_{n+1}\\v_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}u_n\\v_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$

And the sequences are verifying the linear induction

$\begin{cases}u_{n+2}-3u_{n+1}+2u_n=0\\v_{n+2}-3v_{n+1}+2v_n=0\end{cases}$

Solving it classically, the solutions are linear combination of powers of the eigenvalues (or equivalently the roots of $\chi(x)=0$).

Thus $\exists (\alpha,\beta)\in\mathbb R^2\mid u_n=\alpha\, 1^n + \beta\, 2^n$ and similarly for $v_n$ with another set of $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Calculate for $u_0=0,\ v_0=1$ to determine all these constants, and you get the result shown in [automaticallyGenerated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3393946/399263)'s answer.

---

As you can see everything is really all entangled, the classical solving via characteristic equation and the solve via matrix reduction. These methods are just different presentations for the same thing.

Comment: could you please clarify the variant part, I'm sorry I didn't understand it .

Comment: I detailed this second part, hope it is clearer now.